# Pandas: Newbie question on compare and (re)calculate fields with pandas

Tags: pandas, compare

What I need to do is to compare 2 fields in a row in a csv-file:

Data looks like this:

```
store;ean;price;retail_price;quantity
001;0888721396226;200;200;2
001;0888721396233;200;159;2
001;2194384654084;299;259;7
001;2194384654091;199.95;199.95;8
```

in case that "price" is equal to "retail_price" the field retail_price must be reduced by a given percent-value, e.g. -10%

so in the example data, the first and last line should be changed to 180 and 179,955

I´m completely new to pandas and after reading the "getting started" part I did not find anything that I could set upon ...

so any help or hint (just point me in the direction, I will fiddle it out myself then) is appreciated,

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare both values and if same multiple `retail_price` by `0.9` else not in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df['price'].eq(df['retail_price'])
df['retail_price'] = np.where(mask, df['retail_price'].mul(0.9), df['retail_price'])
print (df)
   store            ean   price  retail_price  quantity
0      1   888721396226  200.00       180.000         2
1      1   888721396233  200.00       159.000         2
2      1  2194384654084  299.00       259.000         7
3      1  2194384654091  199.95       179.955         8
```

Or you can use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for multiple only matched rows by `0.9`:

```
mask = df['price'].eq(df['retail_price'])
df.loc[mask, 'retail_price'] *= 0.9

#working like
df.loc[mask, 'retail_price'] = df.loc[mask, 'retail_price'] * 0.9
```

EDIT: for filter rows not matched mask (with Falses in mask) use:

```
df2 = df[~mask].copy()
print (df2)
   store            ean  price  retail_price  quantity
1      1   888721396233  200.0         159.0         2
2      1  2194384654084  299.0         259.0         7


print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Dear Jezrael, i managed to get it working. THANK YOU SO MUCH !

But now i have i litte problem with the output as the output now also has the Row-Number as a new, leading column within the file

e.g.

      store            ean   price  retail_price  quantity
0         1   888721396233  200.00        200.00         2
1         1  2194384654084  299.00        299.00         7

The file mustnt contain this column

btw my complete code ist now:

df['retail_price'] = np.where(mask, df['retail_price'].mul(mulvalue).round(2), df['retail_price'])
print (df)
df.to_csv('output.csv')

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - So need `df.to_csv(file, index=False)` ?

Comment: Thanks again for the hint:

'code' df.to_csv('output.csv', columns=['store','ean','price','retail_price','quantity'],sep=';')

Did the trick :-)

Comment: index=False    -> didnt change anything in the output, whyever ...

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - So my solution not working?

Comment: Damn: i found a culprit now: 

how do i get those lines in the output, that needn´t to be recalculated ?

only those lines that DO have equal values are processed, but i need to prevent the skipped ones too !

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - use `df2 = df[~mask].copy()`

Comment: sorry i dont get it. Cant this be done with an if / Else routine ?

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - I answer for your question `how do i get those lines in the output, that needn´t to be recalculated ?` Answer is `df2 = df[~mask].copy()` i  means filtered rows which are False in mask it eans rows which are not recalculated.

Comment: `df2 = df[~mask].copy()
df.to_csv('output.csv', columns=['store','ean','price','retail_price','quantity'],sep=';', index=False)
print(df2)`

renders to 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [store, ean, price, retail_price, quantity]
Index: []

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - So it means `df2` is empty after `df2 = df[~mask].copy()` and then `print (df2)` ? So there is no `False` values in `print (mask)` ?

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - Or problem is with data in question all working perfectly but in real data not?

Comment: problem is: there IS a value with price NEQ retail_price -> so i don´t get, whats going wrong. i have 3 lines with eqal values, and 1 with non-equal -> but this line isnt appended or "added" to the output at all ...

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - So you test it in data from question? If yes, why not returned 2 rows with index=1,2 ?

Comment: print (mask) only delivers 3 lines with "True) whilst the file has 4 lines (of which 1 is with the non-equal-Data)

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - What is `print (df.to_dict())` with sample data? Because it seems some data related problem.

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - added to answer ouput from data with question (which I copy to my IDE).

Comment: `it lists only the 3 rows with the equal values`, the 4th row with the non-equal data ist not appearing.

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - hmmm, `df2 = df[~mask].copy()` working differently - it return rows if False in mask, added to answer. Not sure about your code, but it seems used `df2 = df[mask].copy()` for filter rows if `True`s in mask.

Comment: i think i found it: it always skips the first line of data ! (Line 2 in the ascii-File) !

Question is now: why ?

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - ya, so problem with read file to DataFrame?

Comment: @MarkusPöschl - I see, remove `header=1, names=['store','ean','price','retail_price','quantity']` so use only `df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep=';')`

Comment: thank you so much ! i also added `dtype={'store': object,'ean': object}` now, so it doesnt change the EAN and Store-ID (removing leading zeros) -> now its perfect !!

Have a nice week and again: thanks for your patience & help ! really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

This ist my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

with open('prozente.txt', 'r') as f:    #create multiplicator from static value in File "prozente.txt"
    prozente = int(f.readline())
mulvalue = 1-(prozente/100)    
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep=';', header=1, names=['store','ean','price','retail_price','quantity'])
mask = df['price'].eq(df['retail_price'])
df['retail_price'] = np.where(mask, df['retail_price'].mul(mulvalue).round(2), df['retail_price'])
df2 = df[~mask].copy()
df.to_csv('output.csv', columns=['store','ean','price','retail_price','quantity'],sep=';', index=False)
print(df)
print(df2)
```

using this as 1.csv:

```
store;ean;price;retail_price;quantity
001;0888721396226;200;200;2
001;0888721396233;200;159;2
001;2194384654084;299;259;7
001;2194384654091;199.95;199.95;8
```

The content of file "prozente.txt" is

```
25
```